# calculating long term daily means from a RASTER in R

Tags: r, raster, netcdf

I have a RasterBrick object in R called z500 (geopotential height of 500 hPa isobaric surface). Its got following description:

```
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 221, 121, 26741, 59900  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
extent     : 14.875, 45.125, 24.875, 80.125  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 
source     : C:/Users/Adam/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpct79pT/raster/r_tmp_2020-10-23_122821_43760_36114.grd 
names      : X1979.01.01.00.50.39, X1979.01.01.06.50.39, X1979.01.01.12.50.39, X1979.01.01.18.50.39, X1979.01.02.00.50.39, X1979.01.02.06.50.39, X1979.01.02.12.50.39, X1979.01.02.18.50.39, X1979.01.03.00.50.39, X1979.01.03.06.50.39, X1979.01.03.12.50.39, X1979.01.03.18.50.39, X1979.01.04.00.50.39, X1979.01.04.06.50.39, X1979.01.04.12.50.39, ... 
min values :             4769.189,             4746.817,             4732.399,             4728.390,             4753.844,             4795.936,             4853.804,             4893.073,             4947.256,             4990.038,             5002.388,             5007.603,             4996.633,             5000.276,             5014.048, ... 
max values :             5815.242,             5813.691,             5810.005,             5814.445,             5810.501,             5802.763,             5810.199,             5813.260,             5812.462,             5805.134,             5807.656,             5807.419,             5806.255,             5801.406,             5811.816, ...
```

So I got 59 900 layers, as I have values of z500 every 6 hours every day since 1.1.1979 till 31.12.2019.

Now, I would like to subset the RasterBrick somehow, so that in each raster, I have values from the same calendar day throughout the whole time series. So it should be 4*41 layers in one sub-raster (4 values a day, 41 years). And finally, I would easily be able to find long term daily mean of z500, but the above described steps are not easy to do for me.

Every help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the days from the names of `z500` and use these as indices

```
# n <- names(z500)
# example data
n <- c("X1979.01.01.00.50.39", "X1979.01.01.06.50.39", "X1979.01.01.12.50.39", "X1979.01.02.00.50.39", "X1979.01.02.06.50.39", "X1979.02.01.12.50.39", "X1980.01.01.00.50.39", "X1980.01.01.06.50.39", "X1980.01.01.12.50.39", "X1980.01.02.00.50.39", "X1980.01.02.06.50.39", "X1980.02.01.12.50.39")
```

Get the relevant part (month-day)

```
md <- substr(n, 7, 11)
md 
# [1] "01.01" "01.01" "01.01" "01.02" "01.02" "02.01" "01.01" "01.01" "01.01"
#[10] "01.02" "01.02" "02.01"
```

And use that with `raster::stackApply`

```
x <- stackApply(z500, md, mean)
```

You can subset like this (but creating an object for each day is a really bad idea).

```
jan1 <- z500[[md ==  "01.01"]]
```

Comment: Its really that easy! Thank you very much!!