# Calculating long-term mean monthly rainfall from interpolated rasters using TERRA package?

Tags: r, terra

I have a SpatRaster object in R called IDW3, estimated using IDW interpolation method. I have `nlyr = 240`, containing 12 months x 20 years. I need to calculate the long-term mean monthly rainfall from the layers, so that I get `nlyr = 12` at the end, in which each layer represents one calendar month (Jan - Dec).

I have tried using the code below, following this thread [calculating long term daily means from a RASTER in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64514678/calculating-long-term-daily-means-from-a-raster-in-r), but I want to verify the code I used.

Any thoughts and comments please?

```r
idw3
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 723, 449, 240  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 100, 100  (x, y)
#> extent      : 624698.7, 669598.7, 640507.8, 712807.8  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. :  
#> sources     : May 1998_masked_idw3.asc  
#>               May 1999_masked_idw3.asc  
#>               May 2000_masked_idw3.asc  
#>               ... and 237 more source(s)
#> names       :     Jan 1998,     Jan 1999,     Jan 2000,     Jan 2001,     #> Jan 2002,     Jan 2003, ... 
#> min values  :           ? ,           ? ,           ? ,           ? ,           ? ,           ? , ... 
#> max values  :           ? ,           ? ,           ? ,           ? ,           ? ,           ? , ... 

## CALCULATE THE LONGTERM MONTHLY MEANS
# get the months substring
month.ltm <- substr(my, 1,3)

# calculate the ltm using tapp funtion in terra
idw3.ltm <- tapp(idw3, month.ltm, mean)
names(idw3.ltm)
#> [1] "May" "Apr" "Aug" "Jan" "Sep" "Jul" "Jun" "Feb" "Dec"
#> [10] "Nov" "Oct" "Mar"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tapp` for that. Here are some example data

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(ncols=10, nrows=10, nlyr=24)
values(r) <- 1:size(r)
```

If the data are ordered by year, and then by month, you can now do

```
x <- tapp(r, 1:12, mean)
```

In other cases you may have to create another index to match the layers that need to be combined. If your data has a time-stamp, there are some shortcuts. In this case you can use `index="months"`

```
time(r) <- as.Date("2000-01-15") + 0:23 * 30.5
y <- tapp(r, "months", mean)
```

Comment: If the data has a time-stamp, some shortcuts exist, as you elaborated. In the case of calculating mean annual rainfall: ```chirps_annual <- tapp(chirps_sh, "years", mean)```

Answer (score 1):

It's been some time since you posted this, but I'd try to solve this for the next one asking. Since your example does not seem to be fully reproducible, let my use my own data for this purpose.

I used [GPCC v2022 data](https://opendata.dwd.de/climate_environment/GPCC/html/fulldata-monthly_v2022_doi_download.html) - the last two decades of monthly data at 0.5° resolution to be precise - from German Weather Service.

```r
library(terra)
#> terra 1.5.21

# define filenames
files <- c("full_data_monthly_v2022_2001_2010_05.nc",
           "full_data_monthly_v2022_2011_2020_05.nc")

# create SpatRaster object
nc_data <- rast(files)

# get variable names
varnames(nc_data)
#>  [1] "precip"                       "numgauge"                    
#>  [3] "infilled_numgauges"           "interpolation_error"         
#>  [5] "interpolation_error_infilled" "diff_new_old_method"         
#>  [7] "precip"                       "numgauge"                    
#>  [9] "infilled_numgauges"           "interpolation_error"         
#> [11] "interpolation_error_infilled" "diff_new_old_method"

# subset dataset to precipitation only
nc_precip <- nc_data["precip"]

# sneak peek
nc_precip
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 360, 720, 240  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
#> extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#> sources     : full_data_monthly_v2022_2001_2010_05.nc:precip  (120 layers) 
#>               full_data_monthly_v2022_2011_2020_05.nc:precip  (120 layers) 
#> varnames    : precip (gpcc full data monthly product version 2022, precipitation per grid) 
#>               precip (gpcc full data monthly product version 2022, precipitation per grid) 
#> names       : precip_1, precip_2, precip_3, precip_4, precip_5, precip_6, ... 
#> unit        : mm/month, mm/month, mm/month, mm/month, mm/month, mm/month, ... 
#> time        : 2001-01-01 to 2020-12-01
```

As you can see, this dataset is quite similar to yours in terms of information at least (except for crs, extent and resolution). A stack of SpatRaster objects with `nlyr = 240` containing monthly precipitation data. What differs most notably is the `time` attribute ranging from 2001-01-01 to 2020-12-01.

However, basically I approached your issue constructing an appropriate time-based index vector as input to `tapp` using `fun = mean`:

```r
# get timestamps from your SpatRaster object
tst <- terra::time(nc_precip) 

# calculate monthly means
lta <- tapp(nc_precip, index = 1:12, fun = mean)

# tidy your names a little bit
names(lta) <- format(tst, "%B") |> unique()

# inspect result
lta
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 360, 720, 12  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
#> extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#> sources     : memory  
#>               memory  
#>               memory  
#>               ... and 9 more source(s)
#> names       :   January,  February,     March,     April,       May,      June, ... 
#> min values  :         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,     ... 
#> max values  :  979.1880,  852.0020,  720.6245,  739.8225,  884.2455, 1590.6805,     ...
```

The result seems plausible from my point of view, but since this is the first time I used `tapp`, I want to make sure the function behaves as expected by re-calculating manually:

```r
# init an empty list for temporary storage purposes
lta <- list()

# loop monthly and calculate the long-term mean
for (i in 1:12) {
  
  idx <- seq(from = i, by = 12, length.out = n_years)
  
  lta[[i]] <- nc_precip[[idx]] |> terra::mean()
}

# create a SpatRast object with nlyr = 12
lta <- terra::rast(lta)

lta
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 360, 720, 12  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
#> extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#> sources     : memory  
#>               memory  
#>               memory  
#>               ... and 9 more source(s)
#> names       :      mean,      mean,      mean,      mean,      mean,      mean, ... 
#> min values  :         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0, ... 
#> max values  :  979.1880,  852.0020,  720.6245,  739.8225,  884.2455, 1590.6805, ...
```

Same results, phew.

**Edit:**

After some weird behaviour yesterday which cannot be reproduced today I can confirm that using `index = months.abb` gives you the same results as using `index = "months"` (as suggested by Robert below in the comments):

```r
tapp(nc_precip, index = month.abb, fun = mean)
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 360, 720, 12  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
#> extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#> source      : memory 
#> names       :       Jan,       Feb,       Mar,       Apr,       May,       Jun, ... 
#> min values  :         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0, ... 
#> max values  :  979.1880,  852.0020,  720.6245,  739.8225,  884.2455, 1590.6805, ...

tapp(nc_precip, index = "months", fun = mean)
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 360, 720, 12  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
#> extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#> source      : memory 
#> names       :        X1,        X2,        X3,        X4,        X5,        X6, ... 
#> min values  :         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0, ... 
#> max values  :  979.1880,  852.0020,  720.6245,  739.8225,  884.2455, 1590.6805, ...
```

Comment: I think you can do `tapp(nc_precip, "months", mean)`.   For your index: given that you have "time" you can directly get the month from that.   `month.abb` works as that is an index of 12 distinct values, but this is equivalent to using 1:12

Comment: Thank you very much for this pointer! Today I'm not able to reproduce the somewhat weird results using `months.abb` myself - getting the same results with `"months"` and `c(1:12)`. Also good to know I do not need the `rep` part creating the index, thanks again!

Comment: Please note that `index = months.abb` does *not* behave like `index = "months"`, except for the special case where the input data has a monthly time-step starting in January.  `index=months` also works for other cases (e.g. daily time step).

Comment: I should have mentioned my statement was strictly limited to this special use case, when working with monthly data beginning with the first month in order to get yearly data. I'll test `index = months` - probably there is also a `index = days` option - with 5-minutely precipitation data for own purposes in the upcoming days. Thank you for the clarification!