# Merge hourly ERA5 netcdf files into daily files with R

Tags: r, average, data-conversion, era5

I have hourly data for maximum temperature from 1970-2022 for all month in NetCDF format (NetCDF of each month contains data of 24 hours from 1970-2022). Can anyone help me out in aggregating hourly data to daily data with R? I have already tried it by directly converting the hourly data to daily and downloading it but it is unable to download such large dataset. (here's the code that I had tried).

```
wf_set_key(service = "cds") 
data=c.retrieve(
'reanalysis-era5-single-levels',
{
'product_type': 'reanalysis',
'variable': 'maximum_2m_temperature_since_previous_post_processing',
'year': [
  '1970', '1971', '1972',
  '1973', '1974', '1975',
  '1976', '1977', '1978',
  '1979', '1980', 
],
'month': [
  '03','04',
  '05', '06',
],
'day': [
  '01', '02', '03',
  '04', '05', '06',
  '07', '08', '09',
  '10', '11', '12',
  '13', '14', '15',
  '16', '17', '18',
  '19', '20', '21',
  '22', '23', '24',
  '25', '26', '27',
  '28', '29', '30','31',
],
'time': [
  '00:00', '01:00', '02:00',
  '03:00', '04:00', '05:00',
  '06:00', '07:00', '08:00',
  '09:00', '10:00', '11:00',
  '12:00', '13:00', '14:00',
  '15:00', '16:00', '17:00',
  '18:00', '19:00', '20:00',
  '21:00', '22:00', '23:00',
],
'area': [
  38, 67, 6,
  99
],
'format': 'netcdf',
 },
 'day_mean'=ct.climate.daily_mean(data,keep_attrs=True)
 if count == 1:
 day_mean_all=day_mean
 else:       
  day_mean_all=ct.cube.concat([day_mean_all, day_mean], dim='time')
  count = count + 1
   return day_mean_all
   'download.nc')
```

---

I am trying to aggregate the hourly data to daily of that month in R.

```
library(ncdf4) 
ncpath <- "D:/MAX_TEMP/" 
ncname <- "adaptor.mars.internal-1681202164.1038315-25242-15-2a718a58-dcd5-4470-9fd2-ddbdede30875_march"   
ncfname <- paste(ncpath, ncname, ".nc", sep="") 
ncin <- nc_open(ncfname) 
print(ncin) 
library(dplyr) 
a1<-ncname %>%
  group_by(time) %>%
    summarize(Mean_Max_Temp = mean(expver))
#Error in UseMethod("group_by")
```

Comment: What is the error message? It sounds like you are requesting a huge amount of data in one go. Most likely you are exceeding the CDS limits, so you should chunk it up by processing smaller time periods

Comment: I had reduced the time period still its failure. So, now I have downloaded hourly data of only a month (from 1970-2022) as a one NetCDF file and I am trying to aggregate the hourly data to daily of that month in R. But (Error in UseMethod("group_by"))        `library(ncdf4)
ncpath <- "D:/MAX_TEMP/"
ncname <- "adaptor.mars.internal-1681202164.1038315-25242-15-2a718a58-dcd5-4470-9fd2-ddbdede30875_march"  
ncfname <- paste(ncpath, ncname, ".nc", sep="")
ncin <- nc_open(ncfname)
print(ncin)
library(dplyr)
a1<-ncname %>% 
group_by(time) %>% 
  summarize(Mean_Max_Temp = mean(expver))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the nice explanation given by Robert Hijmans [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64514678/calculating-long-term-daily-means-from-a-raster-in-r)

I suppose you are familiar with raster brick function to read your netcdf file (Could use package terra as well, but stick to raster::brick for now). You will then need to group the layers by day-mon in other to aggregate over the time dimension, which is hourly in your netcdf.

Finally, use the stackApply () function as shown in the above link. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `terra::tapp` for that.

```
library(terra)
r <- rast("adaptor.mars.internal-1681202164.1038315-25242-15-2a718a58-dcd5-4470-9fd2-ddbdede30875_march.nc")
x <- tapp(r, "days", mean)
```